# Create DATE (first day of week) column using data from two existing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have been trying to create a view of a current table where I create a date by using two columns of the original table. But I cannot get it working..

In the table I have columns 14-52, 1-13, which represent the weeks of a FiscalYear.
In the table the last column is FiscalYear which is set to 2017 for all of the data in this case.

I want to create a DATE column (by using the monday of the specific week) in the view which is based on the week number of the year (the column) and the fiscal year (the column)

So for example we have column "week 14" and column "2017" and I want to get back "20170403" (3th of april, first monday in april 2017).

So in pictures:
Currently I have this:

[image: 1]

I want to create this:

[image: 2]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any specific database engine (SQL-Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL)?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (EmployeeNumber int, 
[1] int, [2] int, [3] int, [4] int, 
[5] int, [6] int, [7] int, [8] int, 
[9] int, [10] int, [11] int, [12] int, [13] int,
[14] int, [15] int, [16] int, [17] int, 
[18] int, [19] int, [20] int, [21] int, 
[22] int, [23] int, [24] int, [25] int, FiscalYear int);
GO
INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES (1,
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
9,10,11,12,13,
1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000, 2017);
GO
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT EmployeeNumber
 ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8)
 ,dateadd (week, CONVERT(int, [Date])
 ,dateadd (year, CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [Date]) < 14 THEN FiscalYear + 1 ELSE FiscalYear END - 1900 , 0)) - 4 - datepart(dw, dateadd (week, CONVERT(int,[Date])
 ,dateadd (year, CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, [Date]) < 14 THEN FiscalYear + 1 ELSE FiscalYear END - 1900 , 0)) - 4) + 1, 112) AS [DATE]
,FiscalYear
,Budget
FROM 
(
    SELECT EmployeeNumber, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], FiscalYear FROM SampleTable
) p
UNPIVOT
(
Budget FOR [Date] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25])
)
AS unpvt
```

I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, almost have what I am after now. Since its fiscal calendar the first 13 weeks (columns [1]-[13])) are in normal calendar year 2018, is it possible to set that in the statement? So the dates of the entries would be in year 2018 for month january, february and march

Answer (score 0):

Use unpivot and few tircks :

I didnt get why 1000 became 1.000 so manage that by yourself:

```
select a.EmployeeNumber,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(WEEKDAY,(DATEADD(WEEK,a.weeks-1,(select cast('01/01/'+ CAST(a.FiscalYear as nvarchar(4)) as date))))) , 
        CAST((DATEADD(WEEK,a.weeks-1,(select cast('01/01/'+ CAST(a.FiscalYear as nvarchar(4)) as date)))) AS DATE)) [Date],a.FiscalYear,a.budget
         from emp e
unpivot
(
budget 
for weeks in ([14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25])
) a
```

The output is:

```
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|EmployeeNumber   |Date         |FiscalYear  |  budget  |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-04-03   |2017        | 1000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-04-10   |2017        | 2000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-04-17   |2017        | 3000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-04-24   |2017        | 4000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-05-01   |2017        | 5000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-05-08   |2017        | 6000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-05-15   |2017        | 7000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-05-22   |2017        | 8000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-05-29   |2017        | 9000     |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-06-05   |2017        | 10000    |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-06-12   |2017        | 11000    |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
|1234             |2017-06-19   |2017        | 12000    |
*------------------*-------------*-----------*----------*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, almost have what I am after now. Since its fiscal calendar the first 13 weeks (columns [1]-[13])) are in normal calendar year 2018, is it possible to set that in the statement? So the dates of the entries would be in year 2018 for month january, february and march.

Comment: Yes you can. Just add columns in unpivoy portion. no other change required. @RLT